# 2D Movement Theory

Tags: c++, opengl, theory, sdl

I have recently been getting into OpenGL/SDL and playing around with objects in 2D/3D Space and as i'm sure most newbies to this area do, have a few queries, about the 'best' way to do something. I quote best, because i'm assuming there isn't a best way, it's personal preference.

So, I have an entity, a simple GL_QUAD, which I want to move around. I have keyboard events setup, i can get the keypress/release events, not a problem.

I have an entity class, which is my GL_QUAD, pseudo implementation....

```
class Entity
{
    void SetVelocity(float x, float y);
}
```

I then have this event handler code...

```
if theEvent.Key = UPARROW AND theEvent.State = PRESSED
    Entity.SetVelocity(0.0f, -1.0f);
else if theEvent.Key = UPARROW AND theEvent.State = RELEASED
    Entity.SetVelocity(0.0f, 0.0f);
```

My question is, is this the best way to move my entity? This has led me to thinking that we could make it a little more complex, by having a method for adjusting the X/Y Velocity, seperately. As SetVelocity would forget me X velocity if i started moving left? So i could never travel diagonally.

For Example...

```
class Entity
{
    void SetXVelocity(float x);
    void SetYVelocity(float y);
}

if theEvent.Key = UPARROW AND theEvent.State = PRESSED
    Entity.SetYVelocity(-1.0f);
else if theEvent.Key = UPARROW AND theEvent.State = RELEASED
    Entity.SetYVelocity(0.0f);
if theEvent.Key = LEFTARROW AND theEvent.State = PRESSED
    Entity.SetXVelocity(-1.0f);
else if theEvent.Key = LEFTARROW AND theEvent.State = RELEASED
    Entity.SetXVelocity(0.0f);
```

This way, if I have an XVelocity and I then press the UPARROW, I will still have my XVelocity, as well as a new YVelocity, thus moving diagonally.

Is there a better way? Am I missing something very simple here?

I am using SDL 1.2, OpenGL, C++. Not sure if there is something in SDL/OpenGL which would help?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is really general since it depends on how you want to model the movement of your objects in your world.

Usually every object has its velocity which is calculated basing on an acceleration and capped to a maximum. This means that a key press alters the acceleration of the object for the specified frame which is then calculated and applied to the current velocity of the object.

This is done through an *update* phase which goes through all the objects and calculates the velocity change according to the object acceleration. In this way you don't bother to modify the velocity itself but you let your engine to do its calculations depending on the state of every object..

Comment: Thanks for that Jack. But surely, if I am only altering the Acceleration, my object is going to speed up every frame? Would a cap be acceptable? So every frame acceleration increments to a max of 5, then it can go no higher? These things are starting to make sense to me, just talking about them.

Comment: You can both cap acceleration (which you usually don't need since you will apply a constant acceleration if the key is pressed) and cap velocity (which makes sense to avoid that the object starts going too fast for what you want to do). So that you can keep pressing the key and applying the acceleration to the final velocity which will be capped to create no problems. I can advice you this book: http://www.amazon.com/Game-Physics-Engine-Development-ebook/dp/B001C4MZC4 it will explain really everything you need :)

Comment: Thanks Jack, it's a lot clearer now and makes sense in reality. Acceleration would always be '1', velocity has a max of '5', at which point, acceleration would become 0, as we can't accelerate any more. Only when we want to stop or travel in another direction do we slow to bring velocity to 0, and then start the process again.

Comment: Yes something like that, but you don't care about the fact that acceleration won't affect final velocity since it's already at maximum. You apply it normally, then you trim velocity down to the cap again! So you don't have to reduce acceleration to 0 if cap is reached :)

Comment: Indeed, I guess it wouldn't hurt either way. From where i'm looking, if I saw Acceleration of '5', it would be misleading, as it's not accelerating any more? But as you say, it's not something that is a big deal. Thanks for your help Jack.

Comment: Your welcome, simulating physics is quite funny and interesting at the same time. The only problem is that requires some background knowledge to model things in a belieavable way.. this why I suggest you to start from a book :)

Answer (score 2):

acceleration is applied over a period of time, so in the example by @jack, you would apply an acceleration 10m/s^2 over a time period of one second.

you should also modify your application to make it [time based](http://www.flashgamesclassroom.com/classroom/actionscript/frame-based-vs-time-based-animation/), not frame based.

have a look at this [basic game physics](http://www.rodedev.com/tutorials/gamephysics/) introduction, and I would also really have a look at the [GameDev.net Physics Tutorials](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/list.asp?categoryid=28#139)

Comment: Jasper, you read my mind. Time Based was my next theory, as i'm aware of the issues caused by frame based games. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the way you want movement to work is that you want the player to move only when a key is held.
In short: your solution is fine.

Some potential gotchas to take consideration of: What happens if both left and right is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you describe here is a simple [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). You have the different directions in which you can move (plus no movement at all) as the states, and the key-events as transitions. This can usually be implemented quite well using the [state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern), but this is often quite painful in C++ (lots of boilerplate code), and might be over the top for your scenario.

There are of course other ways to represent speed and direction of your entity, e.g. as a 2D-vector (where the length gives the speed). This would enable you to easily represent arbitrary directions and velocities.